# How to target a css class nested 5 descendent down another css class

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to use a javascript changing the opacity of .box as I scroll down the page.

```
var $img = $('.vs-current.box');
```

I want to target only .box that are descendent 5 levels down .vs-current.

I do not want to target any .box that is descendent of .vs-right.

Why is .vs-current.box instead targeting all .box?

Thanks

```
<section id="section-1" class="vs-current">
    <div class="vs-content">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="intro">
                <div class="wrapper-client">
                    <div class="box" style="opacity: 5.011437074829932;">
                        <p>Image 1</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box" style="opacity: 4.07266156462585;">
                        <p>Image 2</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box" style="opacity: 3.133886054421769;">
                        <p>Image 3</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box" style="opacity: 2.195110544217687;">
                        <p>Image 4</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box" style="opacity: 1.2563350340136055;">
                        <p>Image 5</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box" style="opacity: 0.3175595238095238;">
                        <p>Image 6</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box" style="opacity: -0.6212159863945578;">
                        <p>Image 7</p>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- END .wrapper-client -->
            </div><!-- END .intro -->
        </div><!-- END .container -->
    </div>
</section>

<section id="section-2" class="vs-right">
    <div class="vs-content">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="intro">
                <div class="wrapper-client">
                    <div class="box" style="opacity: 5.011437074829932;">
                        <p>Item 1</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box" style="opacity: 4.07266156462585;">
                        <p>Item 2</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box" style="opacity: 3.133886054421769;">
                        <p>Item 3</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box" style="opacity: 2.195110544217687;">
                        <p>Item 4</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box" style="opacity: 1.2563350340136055;">
                        <p>Item 5</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box" style="opacity: 0.3175595238095238;">
                        <p>Item 6</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box" style="opacity: -0.6212159863945578;">
                        <p>Item 7</p>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- END .wrapper-client -->
            </div><!-- END .intro -->
        </div><!-- END .container -->
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Do you want that div with `<p>Image 5</p>` get selected?
I think you need this `$('.vs-current .box:nth-child(5)')`, I'm not sure if understand you correct.

Comment: does your selector have a space in it? As you have written it in the question, this will get elements which have both class `.vs-current` and `.box`, so nothing

Comment: by the way , I thought opacity was just between 0 and 1, so negatives and 2.453737,3456437 etc, what are they for, some sort of plugin?

Answer (score 2):

For descendants you want to use

```js
var $img = $('.vs-current .box');
$("#postResult").html($img.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<b>object length: <div id="postResult"></div></b>
<section id="section-1" class="vs-current">
    <div class="vs-content">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="intro">
                <div class="wrapper-client">
                    <div class="box" style="opacity: 5.011437074829932;">
                        <p>Image 1</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box" style="opacity: 4.07266156462585;">
                        <p>Image 2</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box" style="opacity: 3.133886054421769;">
                        <p>Image 3</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box" style="opacity: 2.195110544217687;">
                        <p>Image 4</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box" style="opacity: 1.2563350340136055;">
                        <p>Image 5</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box" style="opacity: 0.3175595238095238;">
                        <p>Image 6</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box" style="opacity: -0.6212159863945578;">
                        <p>Image 7</p>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- END .wrapper-client -->
            </div><!-- END .intro -->
        </div><!-- END .container -->
    </div>
</section>

<section id="section-2" class="vs-right">
    <div class="vs-content">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="intro">
                <div class="wrapper-client">
                    <div class="box" style="opacity: 5.011437074829932;">
                        <p>Item 1</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box" style="opacity: 4.07266156462585;">
                        <p>Item 2</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box" style="opacity: 3.133886054421769;">
                        <p>Item 3</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box" style="opacity: 2.195110544217687;">
                        <p>Item 4</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box" style="opacity: 1.2563350340136055;">
                        <p>Item 5</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box" style="opacity: 0.3175595238095238;">
                        <p>Item 6</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box" style="opacity: -0.6212159863945578;">
                        <p>Item 7</p>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- END .wrapper-client -->
            </div><!-- END .intro -->
        </div><!-- END .container -->
    </div>
</section>
```

Notice that extra space. See result is **7**, not *14*.

Answer (score 0):

you mean like this ?  this edited to add the box class and fade in

```js
$('.vs-current .box:nth-child(5)').css('background-color','green');
$('.vs-current .box:nth-child(5)').fadeTo( 2500,1);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="section-1" class="vs-current">
    <div class="vs-content">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="intro">
                <div class="wrapper-client">
                    <div class="box" style="opacity: 5.011437074829932;">
                        <p>Image 1</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box" style="opacity: 4.07266156462585;">
                        <p>Image 2</p>
                   </div>
                    <div class="box" style="opacity: 3.133886054421769;">
                        <p>Image 3</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box" style="opacity: 2.195110544217687;">
                        <p>Image 4</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box" style="opacity: .3;">
                        <p>Image 5</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box" style="opacity: 0.3175595238095238;">
                        <p>Image 6</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box" style="opacity: -0.6212159863945578;">
                        <p>Image 7</p>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- END .wrapper-client -->
            </div><!-- END .intro -->
        </div><!-- END .container -->
    </div>
</section>

<section id="section-2" class="vs-right">
    <div class="vs-content">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="intro">
                <div class="wrapper-client">
                    <div class="box" style="opacity: 5.011437074829932;">
                        <p>Item 1</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box" style="opacity: 4.07266156462585;">
                        <p>Item 2</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box" style="opacity: 3.133886054421769;">
                        <p>Item 3</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box" style="opacity: 2.195110544217687;">
                        <p>Item 4</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box" style="opacity: 1.2563350340136055;">
                        <p>Item 5</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box" style="opacity: 0.3175595238095238;">
                        <p>Item 6</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box" style="opacity: -0.6212159863945578;">
                        <p>Item 7</p>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- END .wrapper-client -->
            </div><!-- END .intro -->
        </div><!-- END .container -->
    </div>
</section>
```